# Using Bootstrap, how can I put a badge next to a carousel

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have tried everything to put this badge next to a carosuel and nothing seems to work. I have played around with the col-md-6 structure for each div and that doesnt seem to do anything. I have also tried inline-block but that also doesnt seem to change anything.

```
 <div class="container px-1 py-1">
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary rounded">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="user_icon.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="profilepicture">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Why Bootstrap?</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Fast. Stylish. Easy. Bootstrap is easy to use, and looks great.</p>
                    <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Learn
                        More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary border">
            <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
                        aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                        aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                        aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="user_icon.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>First slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
                    data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"
                    data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried col-md-6 and inline block and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a `d-flex` to your main `container` div. Then to place the Badge next to the carousel you need to add `order-2` class to your Badge comp container.

See an example here - https://playcode.io/996467. Hope this will help